# Ubuntu server fingerprint changed and now I can't login to any account via ssh

Tags: server, ssh, login, password

Kind of new to this whole Ubuntu Server thing.

My server got unplugged at some point. Upon bringing it back online, when I tried to login with my account on my laptop, it said the fingerprint changed. I can log in at the physical terminal to all the accounts I have access to, including one with admin privileges, but I can't log in to any of them remotely via ssh, it keeps telling me my password was denied.

Pinging the server from my laptop yields valid responses.

I have enabled password authentication and even remote root login in the sshd_config, although I will say I was using pubkey login before (which also has ceased working).

Any idea on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Does the server has a different IP address now? Which version of Ubuntu? Please copy and paste the exact errors into your question.

Comment: Once you modified the sshd_config on the server, did you then restart the sshd service afterward?